# Carnot cicle problem

Tags: thermodynamics, motors

I'm trying to solve this problem in elementary Carnot cycle study:

I have two (hot and cold) heat fountains of a motor, in air, at temperatures $T_a = 1500^0$C and $T_c = 10^0$C, respectively. The work done by this motor is employed to activate a heat pump, the cold fountain of the heat pump is at $T_c = 10^0$C and the hot fountain is at $T_b = 40^0$C. Both are suppose reversible machines.

> *The fraction between the heat that the motor receives of the fountain and the heat that the heat pump provides to its hot fountain is?*

**My attempt:** We have that both, the motor and the heat pump, can be modeled by a Carnot Cicle model. The question asks: What is $Q_a^M/Q_c^T$? So we have that the work done by the fountains is

$$\tau^M = Q_a^M-Q_c^M$$

But this is the work that it is used to activate the heat pump, so we have that $$\tau^M = Q_b^T$$ 
Then we can manipulate this results to obtain, using that $Q_b^T/T_b = Q^T_c/T_c$

$$Q_c^T\frac{T_b}{T_c} = Q_a^M-Q_c^M = Q_a^M - Q_a^M\frac{T_c}{T_a} = Q_a^M\left(1 - \frac{T_c}{T_a}\right)$$

Then we have that

$$Q_a^M/Q_c^T = \frac{T_b}{T_c}\left(\frac{1}{1 - T_c/T_a}\right)$$

But this gives the wrong answer. The correct one is $Q_a^M/Q_c^T \approx 0,1137 =  11.37$%

Notations: $Q_{a,b,c}$ is the heat in the isotherm given by the temperatures $T_a$ or $T_b$ or $T_c$. The above indices $^M$ means that this is the heat motor and the above indices $^T$ means that it is the heat of the heat pump.